# Angular FormGroup.value puts values in array

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using the [Angular Material Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) to create a simple True / False test. At the end of the test, you hit a submit button that calls a service that gathers the users answers and stores them.

The structure of my app looks like this:

[image: Project structure]

It's quite simple. Here is the typescript code for the questions-stepper that uses the answers service

```
  //Push results to service so other components can use it
  gatherResults(){
    this._answerService.setAnswers(
                          Object.values(this.firstFormGroup.value),
                          Object.values(this.secondFormGroup.value), 
                          Object.values(this.thirdFormGroup.value),
                          Object.values(this.fourthFormGroup.value),
                          Object.values(this.fifthFormGroup.value),
                          Object.values(this.sixthFormGroup.value),
                          Object.values(this.seventhFormGroup.value),
                          Object.values(this.eigthFormGroup.value),
                          Object.values(this.ninthFormGroup.value),
                          Object.values(this.tenthFormGroup.value),
                          Object.values(this.eleventhFormGroup.value),
                          Object.values(this.twelthFormGroup.value)
                          );
    let answers = this._answerService.retrieveAnswers();
    console.log(answers);
  }
```

And here is the full code for the answers service

```
export class AnswersService {

  answers = {};
  constructor() { }

  setAnswers(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12){
    this.answers = {
      answer1 : a1,
      answer2: a2,
      answer3: a3,
      answer4: a4,
      answer5: a5,
      answer6: a6,
      answer7: a7,
      answer8: a8,
      answer9: a9,
      answer10: a10,
      answer11: a11,
      answer12: a12
    }
  }

  retrieveAnswers(){
    return this.answers;
  }

}
```

All of this code works, however, I have one small problem. The format in which the answers object exists. When I log the answers object in the answers service, it returns an object that has arrays in it.

[image: Javascript Object]

Can I change this so that it's more like an object like this

[image: Ideal Layout]

EDIT

I've tried removing the Object.Values when calling the setAnswers function in the answers service. This just gives me another object in the value. This is what you get when you remove it from the first two.

[image: Updated Object]

Comment: It would be better if you can name all the controls by the same name. It will help you with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object.values(object) transforms the object into an array, so if you want the first value only, then you can try this.

```
  //Push results to service so other components can use it
  gatherResults(){
    this._answerService.setAnswers(
                          Object.values(this.firstFormGroup.value)[0],
                          Object.values(this.secondFormGroup.value)[0], 
                          Object.values(this.thirdFormGroup.value)[0],
                          Object.values(this.fourthFormGroup.value)[0],
                          Object.values(this.fifthFormGroup.value)[0],
                          Object.values(this.sixthFormGroup.value)[0],
                          Object.values(this.seventhFormGroup.value)[0],
                          Object.values(this.eigthFormGroup.value)[0],
                          Object.values(this.ninthFormGroup.value)[0],
                          Object.values(this.tenthFormGroup.value)[0],
                          Object.values(this.eleventhFormGroup.value)[0],
                          Object.values(this.twelthFormGroup.value)[0]
                          );
    let answers = this._answerService.retrieveAnswers();
    console.log(answers);
  }
```

And if you want to name all the values by name, you can try this:

```
//Push results to service so other components can use it
gatherResults(){
this._answerService.setAnswers(
                              this.firstFormGroup.value.firstCtrl,
                              this.secondFormGroup.value.secondCtrl, 
                              ..
                              //And similarly for all forms
                              );
let answers = this._answerService.retrieveAnswers();
console.log(answers);
```

Comment: I tried this before and it creates another object within the value. I'll update my answer with a screenshot of what you get when you remove the Object.values from the first two form groups.

Comment: That would help and what this.firstFormGroup.value returns?

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: You can also try the alternative I have suggested.